# Magento: page/html_wrapper block is empty

Tags: magento

Small part of Page.xml:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
     ....
      <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-left.phtml">
             <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header" /> <!-- work -->
             <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="u.Top.Menu" as="u_Top_Menu" translate="label"> <!-- doesn't work -->
                    <label>top menu</label>
                    <action method="setElementTagName"><value>div</value></action>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>sub-menu</value></action>
             </block>
         ...
         </block>
....
```

And in the 2columns-left.phtml output it:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('u_Top_Menu'); ?>
```

But it always retuns empty value. I'm confused here a bit. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What if you try $this->getChildHtml('u.Top.Menu');? Well I agree that cache might be the problem.

Comment: I tried it. it doesn't help, unfortunetly.

Comment: where are you placing the `getChildHtml('u_Top_Menu')`? What is the path to the layout xml and phtml template files?

Comment: 1 more thing - 2-columns-left.phtml is might be rewritten somewhere else. So try to put this echo call to some other files.

Comment: Yes I did echo and evenmore I printed var_dump for $this->getChildHtml('u_Top_Menu'). It gets empty string.

Comment: @Jonathan Day I updated comments on post.  I use page/2columns-left.phtml for my package and other blocks work correct there.

Comment: @Anthony - the full path including theme and design...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what happens when you forget to add the children block to the html wrapper block. Look at this block class source code:

```
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Whether block should render its content if there are no children (no)
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_dependsOnChildren = true;

    /**
     * Render the wrapper element html
     * Supports different optional parameters, set in data by keys:
     * - element_tag_name (div by default)
     * - element_id
     * - element_class
     * - element_other_attributes
     *
     * Renders all children inside the element.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $html = empty($this->_children) ? '' : trim($this->getChildHtml('', true, true));
        if ($this->_dependsOnChildren && empty($html)) {
            return '';
        }
```

...

Answer (score 1):

So far as I can tell you are doing everything correct. The thing that normally trips people up is the `as` vs `name` issue whereby a block is referred in xml via it's `name`, but in templates via it's `as`. You don't appear to have fallen into this trap, so my best guess is that your cache hasn't been cleaned. An `rm -rf var/cache/mage-*` should hopefully fix the issue.

Comment: I turned off cache and tried to clear it manually also. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Zyava is correct, but I have a workaround!

If you don't want to add children to the block, but still need it to render, there is a class function (dependsOnChildren) that allows you to set this `_dependsOnChildren` flag from your layout XML like so:

```
<block type="page/html_wrapper" name="u.Top.Menu" as="u_Top_Menu" translate="label"> <!-- doesn't work -->
    <label>top menu</label>
    <action method="setElementTagName"><value>div</value></action>
    <action method="setElementClass"><value>sub-menu</value></action>
    <!-- This will tell PhP to call $blockClass->dependsOnChildren(0); before rendering. -->
    <action method="dependsOnChildren"><value>0</value></action>
</block>
```

Here is that function (for reference)

app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Wrapper.php @ Line 80

```
/**
 * Setter whether this block depends on children
 * @param $depends
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper
 */
public function dependsOnChildren($depends = '0')
{
    $this->_dependsOnChildren = (bool)(int)$depends;
    return $this;
}
```